# Contract Bridge Games Verses Party Bridge Scoring?

Tags: bridge

In scoring contract rubber bridge, if you make 2 or more games out of 3 you get 500/700 pts for a rubber.  If you make 2 games consecutively before your opponents make a game at all you get 700 pts.  But if your opponents get a game before you make 2 games in a row you only get a 500 rubber.  My question is: in party bridge do you score this the same or do you score 300 pts to each parnership that scores a game and then an additional 200 or 400pts depending on if  they score another game before opponents can score a game? In other words, do you get any additional points for making a game if you don't win the rubber, other than the 100 or 120 below the line?

Comment: Is "party bridge" just rubber bridge played socially, or does it have a separate meaning?

Comment: @TimLymington: The usual understanding is that "party bridge" refers to scoring by "four-deal-sets" instead of rubbers, so that players can be moved around between tables every 30 minutes or so. There are variations, but all utilize some form of [Chicago Scoring](https://www.acbl.org/learn_page/how-to-play-bridge/how-to-keep-score/chicago/) The player movement is usually "progressive", with winners of each round moving up a table and losers moving down. Often players switch partners as they arrive at a table after moving.

Answer (score 1):

Neither - as each hand is scored individually for the Game Bonus of 300 Non Vulnerable and 500 Vulnerable.

One option that I have seen played is to carry part-scores forward after any of the first three deals of a set instead of awarding a Part Score Bonus of 50. When this is done the Part Score Bonus is 100 rather than 50 on the Fourth hand, when the set is closed off. Be sure to discuss in advance with your partner and opponents if this option is in effect.

Answer (score 0):

If a rubber is finished, there is no additional bonus for making a game: if you won, it is part of the rubber bonus, and if you lost it has reduced the opponents' bonus from 700 to 500.

But if for some reason a rubber has to end before one side has won two games, a bonus is awarded in the final score, of 300 for a game and 50 for a part-score. (See [Bridgewebs' scoring rules](http://www.bridgewebs.com/haylingisland/RUBBER%20BRIDGE%20SCORING%20PDF.pdf).)